# XDocument LINQ search based on attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an XML document which I load from the disk

```
XDocument events = XDocument.Load("Content/GameData/events.xml");
```

The contents of this xml are the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Events>
    <level1>
        <NarrationEvent code="lvl1_fridge">
        I can't even remember when I last ate.
        I am not hungry though.
        </NarrationEvent>
        <NarrationEvent code="lvl1_tv">
        Why do I even have a TV?
        Oh right, I use it as a screen for my laptop.
        </NarrationEvent>
        <NarrationEvent code="lvl1_bed">
        Oh man, I am beat.
        </NarrationEvent>
        <NarrationEvent code="lvl1_computer">
        Oh, look at that. The project has been compiled.
        </NarrationEvent>
    </level1>
    <level2>

    </level2>
    <level3>

    </level3>
    <level4>

    </level4>
    <cave>

    </cave>
</Events>
```

I use this code here supposedly select the appropriate NarrationEvent element, based on its attribute "code"

```
IEnumerable<XElement> v =
            (from narrationEvent in events.Elements("NarrationEvent")
             where  (string)narrationEvent.Attribute("code") == code
             select narrationEvent);


foreach (XElement page in v)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("ff");
    narration.Add(page.Value);

}
```

This returns nothing, my XElement Ienumerable is empty. I used breakpoints and the code value is passed to this method just fine. e.g. "lvl1_bed"

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Method to get your NarrationEvent-Element. I have updated your code accordingly.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> v = from narrationEvent in events.Descendants("NarrationEvent")
                          where narrationEvent.Attribute("code").Value == code
                          select narrationEvent;
```

Comment: It seems like you were right, I don't understand the logic though. evets.Elements() looks only at the root?

Comment: @A.A. Elements() only checks the direct childs of a node, while Descendants() checks all direct and indirect childs